# Groups such that inclusion on collection of all its subgroup is a total order

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Characterize the Groups with the following property:

Suppose G is any group such that for any two subgroups, H and K either H $\subseteq$K or K $\subseteq$ H. Now what can we tell about cardinality, also about abelianess(Information about commutator subgroup) of the group?

Comment: What do you think the answer might be? Make a conjecture!

Comment: Yikes, yes, I was assuming countably generated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer to the question, but I'll show that such groups are abelian and torsion (i.e., each element has finite order).

Abelianity:
Suppose $G$ is a group with this property, and we show that it is abelian. Take $a$ and $b$ be two elements of the group $G$. Let $H=\langle a \rangle$ and $K=\langle b\rangle$. Either $H$ contains $K$ or vice versa, meaning that $b$ is a power of $a$ or vice versa.

Suppose WLOG that $b$ is a power of $a$, writing $b=a^k$ gives:
$$
ab=aa^k=a^{k+1}=a^k a=ba
$$
Because $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, we conclude that $G$ is abelian.

I now claim that each element of $G$ has finite order:
 Take any $a\in G$, and let $H=\langle a^2 \rangle$, $K=\langle a^3\rangle$. Either $H$ contains $K$ or vice versa, meaning that $a^2$ is a power of $a^3$ or vice versa. Thus we find some integer $k$ such that one of the following is true:
$$
a^{2k}=(a^2)^k=a^3 \;\;or\;\; a^{3k}=(a^3)^k=a^2
$$
thus $a^{2k-3}=id$ or $a^{3k-2}=id$ (where $id$ is the group identity), and both of the exponents are non-zero (as $k$ is an integer). Thus $a$ has finite order, where $a\in G$ was chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Sounds to me like the next step is showing that there is a prime $p$ such that all elements have order some power of $p$. Then it starts to smell like the Prüfer groups.

Comment: @Myself Indeed so...and finite cyclic groups of order a power of a prime.

Comment: Yes the finite case must be done first, then for the infinite case it seems most feasible to exhibit the group as direct limit of its subgroup of elements of order $p^i$.

Comment: A nice piece in simplifying some of the arguments is to note that the property is inherited by subgroups. This immediately gives that any finite subgroup is cyclic of prime power order (for some fixed prime).

Comment: Are prufer groups only infinite groups having this property?

Comment: @Mambo Well, it is certainly fairly straightforward to prove that if such a group is infinite, then it is divisible.

Comment: as every element has finite order

Comment: All elements in such a group clearly have order power of $p$ for some fixed prime $p$. If $G$ is infinite, then you can build a chain of subgroups $1 < \langle x_1 \rangle < \langle x_2 \rangle < \cdots$  such that each $x_i$ has order $p^i$ and then $G$ must equal to the union of this chain. I think that implies that $G$ must be the Prüfer $p$-group

Answer (score 3):

Here is an extension of the answer by Miel Sharf, proving that such a group is either a finite cyclic group of prime power order or a Prüfer group.

First, we deal with the case where $G$ is finite. In this case, $G$ has a unique maximal subgroup, and hence is generated by any element not in this subgroup, so it is cyclic. It must also have prime power order, or it would have two non-trivial subgroups intersecting trivially (by picking them of distinct prime orders).

Next, we note that the property of subgroups being totally ordered is inherited by subgroups, so we conclude that there are no elements of infinite order, as that would give an infinite cyclic subgroup, and infinite cyclic groups do not satisfy the requirements. It also shows that all finite subgroups are cyclic of prime power order for some fixed prime, so in fact all elements have prime power order.

Finally, we assume that $G$ is infinite and wish to show that it is a Prüfer group, i.e. that for each $x\in G$ there are precisely $p$ solutions in $G$ to the equation $y^p = x$. To see this, we prove that this is in fact the case for any $x$ in a cyclic $p$-group which is not a generator (and then it follows for $G$ by noting that $\langle x\rangle$ sits inside a larger cyclic $p$-group in $G$).

So let $H$ be a cyclic $p$-group and $x\in H$ be an element which is not a generator. If $y$ is a generator for $H$ then $x = y^{pn}$ for some $n$, and we see that the elements $z$ with $z^p = x$ are precisely those of the form $y^{nk}$ where $k\equiv 1\pmod{|x|}$. That there are precisely $p$ solutions to this follows since $y^{n(1 + m|x|)} \neq y^{n(1+m'|x|)}$ when $1\leq m < m'\leq p-1$ while $y^{n(1+ p|x|)} = y^n$.

Comment: Why is $G$ countable?